# ValueError: Unexpected result of `predict_function` (Empty batch_outputs). Please use `Model.compile(..., run_eagerly=True)`,

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, grid-search

I tried using GridSearchCV() but I also got errors so I wrote a very time consuming code that returns the metrics I want to evaluate my model. Here it is :

```
def df_to_new(df,window_size): 
    df_as_np = df.to_numpy()
    X = []
    y = []
    for i in range(len(df_as_np)-window_size):
        row = [[a] for a in df_as_np[i:i+window_size]]
        X.append(row)
        label = df_as_np[i+window_size]
        y.append(label)
        
    return np.array(X),np.array(y)  

from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
import os
checkpointpath = 'C:\\Users\\USER\\trainingFORLOOP_daily/cp.ckt'
cp = ModelCheckpoint(checkpointpath, save_best_only=True,verbose=1)     
EPOCH = [30,150,300]
learningRates = [0.0001,0.00001]
batchSize = [15,20,40]
win_size = [5,15,25]
dropout_rate = 0.2
num_features = 1
for i in learningRates:
    for j in EPOCH:
        for k in batchSize:
            for l in win_size:
                X,y = df_to_new(Ac13,l)

                #Split the data
                perc_train = 0.8
                limit_train = int(np.floor(len(Ac13)*perc_train))
                xtrain,ytrain = X[:limit_train],y[:limit_train]
                xval,yval = X[limit_train:],y[limit_train:]
                
                #create the model
                model1 = Sequential() 
                model1.add(InputLayer((l,1))) 
                model1.add(LSTM(128))
                model1.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))
                model1.add(Dense(86,'relu'))
                model1.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))
                model1.add(Dense(1,'linear'))
                model1.summary()
                model1.compile(loss=MeanSquaredError(),optimizer = 
                       Adam(learning_rate=i),
                       metrics=[RootMeanSquaredError()],run_eagerly=True)
                model1.fit(xtrain,ytrain,validation_data=(xval,yval),batch_size=k,epochs=j,callbacks=[cp],shuffle=False)
                model1.save("my_model")
                model1 = load_model("my_model")
                           
                train_predictions = model1.predict(xtrain).flatten() 
                train_results = pd.DataFrame(data={'TrainPredictions':train_predictions,'Actual values':ytrain})
                train_results
                scale = len(train_predictions)
                val_predictions = model1.predict(xval).flatten()
                val_results = pd.DataFrame(data='ValidatePredictions':val_predictions,'Validation values':yval})
```

I am getting the following error (Full traceback):

```
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_19052/292377201.py in <module>
     51                 plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor =(0.75, 1.15), ncol = 2)
     52                 plt.show()
---> 53                 val_predictions = model1.predict(xval).flatten() # flatten() removes the brackets inside the data
     54                 val_results = pd.DataFrame(data={'Validate Predictions':val_predictions,'Validation values':yval}) #yval are the actual values
     55                 val_results

~\anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu-cuda8\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     65     except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
     66       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     68     finally:
     69       del filtered_tb

~\anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu-cuda8\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in predict(self, x, batch_size, verbose, steps, callbacks, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1995             callbacks.on_predict_batch_end(end_step, {'outputs': batch_outputs})
   1996       if batch_outputs is None:
-> 1997         raise ValueError('Unexpected result of `predict_function` '
   1998                          '(Empty batch_outputs). Please use '
   1999                          '`Model.compile(..., run_eagerly=True)`, or '

ValueError: Unexpected result of `predict_function` (Empty batch_outputs). Please use `Model.compile(..., run_eagerly=True)`, or `tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)` for more information of where went wrong, or file a issue/bug to `tf.keras`.
```

Any suggestions?
I did the same approach but with hourly data and it worked quite well without any errors. The hourly code is the same as the daily code(this one) the only thing that changed is that the data in the hourly code was summed in a day and the daily code data was obtained.

Comment: Please add the *full* error traceback to the question; in particular it's important to know which line exactly throws the error. At a glance, you might want to double check (e.g. using `print` statements) that the datasets you are passing to the model are not empty (length 0) for some reason.

Comment: @xlurch0 thanks for answering. I just added the full traceback. I used the same code for hourly data and it worked. The only changes i made was to sum the data from the hourly data into daily data. Nothing else. But taking your suggestion showed me that the dataset I'm passing is empty because "limit_train" is sometimes greater than the length of X thus xval would be empty. Do you think that changing limit_train=int(np.floor(len(X)*perc_train)) is the right correction?

Comment: Assuming that `Ac13` is the hourly data (it's not defined in the code you posted) and `X` is the daily, then yes, you will definitely have to use the size of the data you actually use (`X`) to define the train-validation split.

Comment: @xdurch0 your assumption is on point (I left out of this code excerpt on purpose). Thanks for the insight. Helpful indeed!

Answer (score -1):

There are a few things wrong with your code.

1. You are creating your model inside the training loop. So that’s wrong. Unless you want to train a new version at each epoch. Your model should be defined and compiled before you start training.
2. Depending on which version of tensorflow you you are using you should enable eager execution before you declare the model. That lets you train the model without creating a session and a scope.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is incorrect; the loops are for hyperparameter searches, it's *not* a training loop. They are training using `fit`. They also aren't using sessions or "scopes" (?) anywhere.